# Copy and Paste using array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying to create a relatively simple copy and paste procedure. I have certain cell addresses stored in an array (Results1()) and I am trying to extrapolate the row which it is in to copy an entire row of data into another Excel sheet. I have the following so far and currently I am getting an object required error when I try to define what my 'NextRow' is. Any advice or feedback would be greatly appreciated!

```
For i1 = LBound(Results1) To UBound(Results1)
    Set NextRow = Worksheets("searchresult").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                Range(Results(i1)).EntireRow.Copy NextRow
Next i1
```

Editted code

```
    For i1 = LBound(Results1) To UBound(Results1)
        Worksheets("properties").Select
        Set p1results = Range(Results1(i1))
        p1results.EntireRow.Copy
            With Worksheets("SearchResult").Select
                NextRow = Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
            End With
    Next i1
```

Update: In actuality my data ranges only range from columns D:P so when I count rows I count from column D (4) because columns A-C are empty ranges.  Would this affect the way it is pasting my data?

```
       On Error Resume Next
   For i1 = LBound(Results1) To UBound(Results1)
        Set NextRow = shSearchResult.Cells(shSearchResult.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        shProperties.Range(Results1(i1)).EntireRow.Copy NextRow
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            MsgBox "Bad address" & Results1(i1)
        End If
    Next i1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few potential causes here:

Your for loop references **Results1** but your copy references **Results**  (typo in question? or route cause?)

In your `Set NextRow =` line references `.Cells(Rows.Count,` unqualified, Rows refers to the active sheet not `"searchresult"` sheet.  Probably not what you intended, but also will meke no difference in this case.

Likewise `Range(Results(i1))` refers to the active sheet, may be ok - depends on the wider context of your application

I suspect that your imediate problem is that `NextRow` has not been `DIM`'d.  Try adding

`Dim NextRow as Range` to your Sub

In general it is good practice to use `Option Explicit` (first line in your module).  This forces explicit declaration of all variable.

**EDIT**

based on your edit a `"Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed"` error may be caused by an invalid adress string

Your first code was actually better than your second.  Here's a refactor version

```
Sub zxx()
    Dim Results1(0 To 1) As Variant
    Dim i1 As Long
    Dim NextRow As Range
    Dim shProperties As Worksheet
    Dim shSearchResults As Worksheet


    '  other code ...

    Set shSearchResults = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("searchresult")
    Set shProperties = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("properties")

    On Error Resume Next
    For i1 = LBound(Results1) To UBound(Results1)
        Set NextRow = shSearchResults.Cells(shSearchResults.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        shProperties.Range(Results1(i1)).EntireRow.Copy NextRow
    Next i1


End Sub
```

To detect bad addresses try adding `On Error Resume Next` before the For and

```
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            MsgBox "Bad Address " & Results1(i1)
        End If
```

after the copy (inside the for loop)

**EDIT2**

Copying an `EntireRow` into a single cell only works if the single cell is in column A because because the EntireRow range overhangs the right hand side of the sheet.

Use this to offset back to column A

```
Set NextRow = _
    shSearchResults.Cells(shSearchResults.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -3)
```

Comment: @ren Glad to help, and welcome to SO.  BTW if an answer solves your problem you should accept it 9click the tick) That how SO works

Comment: Chris, thanks for the suggestion, but when I try to run the code I am getting an 'object required' error on the 'Set NextRow=...' line.  Any explanations on why this might be?

Comment: @ren do you have the Dim NextRow as Range in place?  'object required'  error means NextRow is not an object.  Without a Dim (and no Option Explicit) variables default to Variant

Comment: @Chris Neilson ya I just realized I had to change my variable definition for NextRow.  Trying to debug a massive code is rather time consuming.  The macro isn't crashing anymore but it is not displaying any search results currently.  It's an improvement at least!

Comment: @ren progress then... feel free to post another question on other aspects of your code (in answering I did a mockup and it does copy the row addressed in Results1.  If its not giving the expected results I guess the addresses contained in Results1 are suspect)

Comment: @Chris Neilson I added in the if error statement to see what was wrong and as far as I can tell, the Results1() array contain the right cell references b/c the msg box displays it but it is not pasting the entire row into the searchresult sheet.  I've updated the code above, i would really appreciate it if you can take a quick look for any errors!

Answer (score 0):

You never use the With Statement, so just do this instead:

```
For i1 = LBound(Results1) To UBound(Results1)
    Worksheets("properties").Select
    Set p1results = Range(Results1(i1))
    p1results.EntireRow.Copy
    Worksheets("SearchResult").Select
    NextRow = Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste           
Next i1
```

or better:

```
For i1 = LBound(Results1) To UBound(Results1)
    Worksheets("properties").Range(Results1(i1)).EntireRow.Copy
    Worksheets("SearchResult").Cells(Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Paste
Next i1
```

Depending on what you're doing, you might want to use PasteSpecial instead.